# Ef Core 7 table-valued function with nullable parameters in postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

In my postgres db I have a table-valued function with several parameters and some of them are optional (default null).
I want to map this function in my net 7 app.
My context definition looks like this

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetMyEntitiesList(Guid a, string b, int c, int? d, bool? e, Guid? f)
        => FromExpression(() => GetMyEntitiesList(a, b, c, d, e, f));
```

and OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(
     typeof(MyContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetMyEntitiesList),
     new[] { typeof(Guid), typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(int?), typeof(bool?), typeof(Guid?)) }
);
```

When I try to add migration terminal output results in

> Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.

I have no idea what it means.

How can I solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: FYI you can use `new Func<...>(this.GetMyEntitiesList).Method` with the right type parameters to obtain a `MethodInfo`. Particularly useful when you have a large number of overloaded generic parameters.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30142 Does `MyEntity` have a non-null class property? Maybe a string?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yep. Looks like that is the reason.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `int?` use `Nullable<int>` like this:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(
    typeof(MyContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetMyEntitiesList),
    new[] { typeof(Guid), typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(Nullable<int>), typeof(Nullable<bool>), typeof(Nullable<Guid>)) }
);
```